# I am afraid of dealing people smarter and more skilled than me!

Tags: management, leadership

I have a dream to create a robot making company. I have graduated in AI field and have some ideas about it, but as the robot making is a multi deciplinary work and needs Electrical and mechanical engineering knowledges as well, I don't know what can I do for those parts? I mean how can I hire proper electrical/mechanical engineers? How should I lead them when I don't have skills in their field? Even if I do hire CTO guys to lead them, how can I evaluate those CTO guys's work and understand if they are screwing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I treat people working under me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30894/how-do-i-treat-people-working-under-me)

Comment: Are you still looking to do AI work? If so, *you* probably want to be the CTO while you hire someone else to run the company.

Comment: Why was this closed? Yes, there are a lot of question marks, but OP is essentially asking the same thing each time. Don't close the question, edit it to be more concise if you feel it needs it. I (and at least 7 upvotes) don't see any problems with asking how to lead multidisciplinary teams without experience in those disciplines. Vote to reopen.

Comment: i vote to keep it closed as too broad. It basically asks "how to hire people", because you always hire people to solve problems you can't or don't have resources to solve yourslelf

Answer (score 11):

There's two parts to this question.

**First part: "I am afraid of dealing with people smarter and more skilled than me!"**

Uh, no.  *Terrible* way of looking at it.  If you're a manager, your goal should be to hire as smart, as competent, and industrious of people as you can.  If you don't do that?  Oh, sure, you'll be smarter than your underlings... but your team will suck and your performance will suffer as a result.

If it helps, picture it this way: Alice Q Genius and Bob Mehville both are looking for a CTO job.  You decide to hire Bob... and Alice goes to work for another company, quite likely a competitor.  Which company fares better - the one that got the 'meh' CTO, or the one that got the whip-smart one?  Clearly the company that hires Alice is going to be better off - which is doubly worse if that 'other company' is competing with yours.  And imagine if Bob Mehville thinks the same as you, and it comes time to hire some developers/engineers/whatever, where everyone is 'not quite as smart' as Bob?  Care to imagine what talent your company would be losing, simply because management doesn't want smart employees?

**The second part is this:  "how can I evaluate those CTO guys's work and understand if they are screwing?"**

My boss doesn't know C#.  He doesn't know SQL.  He doesn't know the APIs of the vendors we work with.  Or *any* of that.

But that doesn't mean he doesn't make sure I'm not goofing around all day.  All he has to know is:

- What's Kevin generally working on?
- What's the timeframe of his current tasks?
- Are the clients happy?

That's the part that I think you're missing.  You're viewing this as "I'm a AI expert and I want to run an robotics company - but I don't have the engineering knowledge!"

No, the skillset you're missing isn't engineering: it's management.  If you're going to run a company, your important skillset isn't the nuts-and-bolts of AI: it's how to manage people and how to navigate the business world.

Comment: Very thank you Kevin, but I still have a problem with "What's the timeframe of his current tasks?". Who should create this timeframe? If the developer/engineer must do it him/herself, how can I evaluate it, If I have not enough knowledge about the work?

Comment: Why do you feel *you* have to set the timeframe?  If my boss asks me to "Develop a SQL stored proc that does X, Y, and Z," and I tell him, "That'll take me about 3 weeks." ... he'll generally trust me that it'll take 3 weeks.  Especially if I'm able to give regular status updates on what parts I'm working on or have finished.  My boss might not know *how* to do what I'm doing, but that doesn't mean he can't *manage* what I'm doing.  That's why I said you're missing a management skillset.  Part of management is finding good employees and then empowering them to do a good job.

Comment: It's the manager's job to know what value the company will get from having the task done, and whether that is the best use of Kevin's time for three weeks.

Comment: In the comment, OP is asking how to know if it's actually 3 weeks when Kevin says 3 weeks. That response was kind of a non-answer. You indirectly said your manager *trusts* you, so is that all there is to it? Trust the engineer and hope you don't get conned?

Comment: @Mars If you can't trust the person doing the work, who can you trust? What's the concern? That the employee says it takes 3 weeks, knocks out the job in an hour, and spends the rest of the time playing online poker? I'd hope that someone with a track record of success at past companies and incentives to succeed at this one wouldn't do that. But practically, wouldn't that sort of thing become apparent soon enough? Especially if they were working on a team with others with similar skills. Perhaps there's a separate question here on evaluating performance of employees with skills you don't have.

Comment: "*how can I evaluate those CTO guys's work and understand if they are screwing?*" @ZachLipton That's not a separate question, it's literally the question at hand. And yes, saying 3 weeks and knocking out the job in an hour is likely the concern. Another concern would probably be shoddy workmanship. I've seen "engineers" with "X years experience in Y technology" who failed to deliver on even simple tasks, so the problem *does* exist. That's why "hiring departments* are *departments,* not just an automated system

Comment: Also, note that the part about hiring people with a proven history is a different answer!

Comment: I think everyone might be arguing a tempest in a teapot.  The point behind all of it is: this is a *managerial* skillset (being able to manage employees, being able to evaluate effort/performance, etc.)  The OP was under the impression that they were hosed because they didn't have *engineering* skills.  I'm trying to tell them: forget about the engineering.  Start trying to improve in *managerial* skill sets.  Because I'm sure we can all agree, the OP's problem is *not* that they're not a robotics engineer.

Comment: @Kevin I'd argue that the fact that they aren't a robotics engineer *is* a problem. I haven't met a strong manager who didn't have a related tech background, and diving in without a background is setting yourself up to be scammed

Comment: Also consider what kind of people are going to want to work for OP... "Hey, I'm making a company. We're gonna make the greatest robots, the best robots of all time. They're gonna be great. I've never made a robot before, but they're gonna be great. I just need YOU."

Comment: Thank you guys! I think maybe another problem is great guys with shining/proven background prefer to work in great companies with bigger projects, money, etc. So evaluating junior engineers to hire and trusting them and also leading them and defining tasks/timeframes for them needs the founder to have enough knowledge/skills/experience  also in their field. Because of this I thought about hiring CTOs for doing it, but I think still the same problem remains with evaluating junior CTOs to hire.

Comment: For example two engineers will come for CTO job. Person A says I have done these projects and think I can done yours in 6 months, Person B will come and says I have same projects done and think it takes 1 year to done your project. I see their background and think they are at the same level(although another question arises how can I really understand their skill level, maybe one worked in smaller project/company but more smart and skilled) but with different estimations. How can I find that which one is better to trust?

Comment: @ensan3kamel I don't think "junior CTO" exists...  As for how to really understand their skill level--you can't. You could get a third opinion, but if that differs as well, then you have no way to tell who to believe and must instead base your judgment on the risks associated. You *could* pay each CTO for their time and have them write a detailed proposal, with a work-breakdown general enough that even you can understand. You can then compare the parts where each candidate's estimates differ

Comment: Another thing to remember is that senior/capable engineers have higher salaries, but often junior engineers are *more* expensive, because bug-fixes and failures cost money too!

Answer (score 7):

In general, you want to hire people who have a proven history of success in the role you hire them for and who share your vision for the company. It’s not expected that you have in-depth knowledge of every skill your subordinates/partners possess (though it helps to have at least a high level understanding of what they’re doing.)

Don’t confuse leadership with micromanagement. As Steve Jobs put it, "It doesn't make sense to hire smart people and tell them what to do; we hire smart people so they can tell us what to do."

> I am afraid of dealing people smarter and more skilled than me!

You need to get over this fear right now if you want to be successful in business. First of all, different kinds of people are better in different areas. You can't possibly expect to be the best at everything. Secondly, the success of the company is more important than satisfying your own ego. The last thing you want is for the people you hire to not show their best work because the boss is afraid of getting outshined.

Answer (score 3):

A business like that isn't going to be easy to setup. Not only will you need engineers but you will need legal, marketing etc...

The majority of your staff will be doing things you don't understand yourself. You hire people with proven experience (via portfolios and references) and trust them. You will know if they aren't performing by the results they produce.

Comment: What magic do you use to know if they aren't performing, based on the results? If I say "hey, i did this thing" and you don't know how to check that my thing is actually a thing, then who do you know that i did a thing, before it's too late?

Comment: I mean, i think you're in general correct, but if the answer is "you have to trust people," then the next obvious question will be "how to know who to trust?"

Comment: You have to use your judgement. It isn't your job to check, as you don't have the time or skills. That's why you hired them in the first place. All you can do is look at the thing, and think either: yes that looks right, or nah that looks wrong. - Also you should have several engineers. If they all agree it's good then that's what you go with.

Comment: In the situation it's wrong or they aren't actually building what they say, then that's just business i'm afraid, it happens.

Comment: I think there is much more that you can do besides just trusting someone. That's why "hiring departments" exist. Personality tests, specialized knowledge tests, interviews, recommendations, showing a portfolio--these are all techniques that are believed to increase your chance of finding someone who can and will perform well

Comment: Probationary periods are also common

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have pointed out, you'll need management skills more than you'll need engineering skills.

**But you'll still need engineering skills.**
Even if you have great management knowledge, I'd bet the amount of competent managers in the IT space without tech experience are far less than those who have worked first in a technical role.

It's nice to dream big, but you also need to ground those dreams in reality. If robotics is really your dream, I don't think you should have any issue with working in industry (at least at first), hopefully alongside those interdisciplinary people. When you have a more complete grasp of things, you'll be able to better achieve your dream.